# Dock folder shortcut: Is it possible to change the sort order of files in subfolders?

Tags: macos, dock, folders, sort

I have a shortcut to a folder in the Dock.

Here is how this folder is configured:

[image]

This folder contains several subfolders. When I enter a subfolder by hovering the mouse cursor over a subfolder title, the files in the subfolder are, by default, listed in ascending order by Name.

Changing the *"Sort by"* value in the above context-menu only affects the order of the items in the folder itself, not those in its subfolders.

Is it possible to change the ordering method of the files in the **subfolders** (e.g., to *descending* order by Name or Date Modified)?

<sub>Note: This question is strictly concerned with the order of files in the Dock pop-up mini-window in List view, not a proper Finder.app window.</sub>

---

<sub>OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.6.</sub>

---

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. The subfolder will open in anew window or tab and just select how to list the new folder. You can select the column name and click on it and it will sort contents in a decreasing or increasing order. A column header is shown below.

[image: Annotated screenshot of Finder window, showing column headers]

Comment: This changes the sort-order of a Finder.app window. I am specifically inquiring about the sort-order of files in the small, pop-up, preview window that appears when you hover over a subfolder title, after clicking on a Dock folder.

Comment: This isn't what was asked. OP asked about sorting subfolders in list view in the dock.